that's all I care
What does the sentence
a. That's all I care.
mean?
I don't think it means the same as
b. That's all I care about.
(b) to me means that is the only subject that interests me.
(a) seems to be about the extent to which I care about something.
I think (a) is a very idiomatic phrase.
I heard it in a film.
I think this would provide a similar context:
I learned a joke to tell John. That's all I care about him.
The idea seems to be that I don't care about him more than that. That's as far as I would go for him.
Many thanks.

I don't think (a) is a very idiomatic phrase. I've never encountered it, and I have no idea what it might mean. Please give some actual examples of where you're finding it. Though to be honest, if I don't know it then you probably don't need to either. It is idiomatic in certain contexts to say "That's how much I care" (literally or sarcastically, after a statement showing some degree or lack of degree of solicitude on the part of the speaker).

Thank you very much, FumbleFingers. Indeed, if you don't know it then I absolutely don't need to. I heard it in a sitcom. Dialogue in film can at times be incorrect, or unnatural or....

Well, you have your answer. I’m voting to close this question because It's about an apparently one-off "unusual" line in an unidentified movie. Here are multiple written examples of That's how much I care as described above.

If you can, give the actual context in which you heard it, rather than a "similar" one, just in case there can be a helpful answer about it.
